# How to prevent a particular color to appear from the bubbles of a dc.js bubble chart

Tags: dc.js

I am visualizing the bubble chart using dc.js. The color of the bubbles are seem to be appearing randomly. But I don't want a particular color to appear in the chart as it matches with the background color. How can I do that? For example consider the following ideal example of the chart [bubble chart](http://jsfiddle.net/0w3xnbu0/5/)

I don't want the red color/ gray color to appear in the chart. How can I do it? Is there anything to do with the div

```
 <div class="row">
        <div id="bubble-chart" class="dc-chart">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the colors by putting something like this in the bubblechart properties.  In my tinkering with it, the last value is the one that changes the colors of the bubbles, but they are all a similar color, some lighter, some darker.

```
    .colors(['#ccc', '#E2F2FF','#C4E4FF','#9ED2FF','#81C5FF','#6BBAFF','#51AEFF','#36A2FF','#1E96FF','#0089FF','#0061B5'])
```

See https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html